# Crash in UIwebview after sometime (related to URLAssetWorkQueue thread)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiwebview, ios7

Hi I am using a web view in my app and intermittently i get a crash with
logs as follows :

```
#0  0x02c73a33 in __CFURLCache::SetMemoryLimit(long, long) ()
#1  0x02c73a25 in _CFURLCacheSetMemoryLimit ()
#2  0x0a65e364 in figHTTPRequestRunOnce ()
#3  0x026f5719 in __pthread_once_handler ()
#4  0x026059b0 in _os_once ()
#5  0x026f56c8 in pthread_once ()
#6  0x0a65d3cc in FigHTTPRequestCreate ()
#7  0x0a52d8cc in FigCFHTTPOpen ()
#8  0x0a5c394a in fbfs_CreateFlumeAsync ()
#9  0x0a5c305c in FigByteStreamFactoryCreateStreamFromURLWithOptionsAsync ()
#10 0x0a5c26b9 in FigByteStreamFactoryCreateStreamFromURLWithOptions ()
#11 0x0a6446ac in EnsureContentStreamCreated ()
#12 0x0a63db26 in EnsureAssetTypeEstablished ()
#13 0x0a63f58e in URLAssetValidationWorkFunction ()
#14 0x023694b0 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#15 0x0235707f in _dispatch_queue_drain ()
#16 0x02356e7a in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()
#17 0x02357e1f in _dispatch_root_queue_drain ()
#18 0x02358137 in _dispatch_worker_thread2 ()
#19 0x026f5dab in _pthread_wqthread ()
```

After relaunching app keeps crashing. 
Can anyone please help me out on this?

Comment: post some code may help

Comment: There's is no magic code as such Just loading some urls in web view one by one when user clicks on those link.

Comment: I have same issue using a NSURLCache subclass and on Xcode5 iOS7 Simulator. Not without `+[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:]` nor on a device. I did debugging, but not resolved yet.

Comment: Hello, 
It seems that crash occurs only on simulator (iOS 7.0.3), especially when playing a video, or loading some url which contains a video playing side by side. 
It never occurs on device.
Seems like a simulator bug for me.

Comment: @hiroshi SDUrlCache? I have the same issue with it.

Comment: @yebw No, I use a custom NSURLCache subclass.